# How to open a terminal horizontally on the right side of vim

Tags: terminal, vim-windows, vim8

I'm using vim 8 and I set a shortcut to open a terminal in my vim.

```
nnoremap <F5> :wa<CR> \| :term ++kill=term<CR>
```

It works except that it opens a terminal vertically as below:

```
--------------------
|        |some file|
|nerdtree|----------
|        |terminal |
--------------------
```

What I need is to put the terminal on the right side:

```
-----------------------------
|        |         |        |
|nerdtree|some file|terminal|
|        |         |        |
-----------------------------
```

How can I change the shortcut of `<F5>` to achieve this?

Comment: Have a look at the different command modifiers, starting at `:h :vertical`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`:vertical`](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#%3Avertical) and [`:botright`](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#%3Abotright) modifiers.

```
nnoremap <F5> :wa \| vertical botright term ++kill=term<CR>
```

Or:

```
nnoremap <F5> :wa<CR>:vertical botright term ++kill=term<CR>
```

(Also note that you need one of `<CR>` or `\|`, not both. Your original command ends up executing the [Normal mode `|` motion](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#bar), which moves the cursor to the first column, followed by a space that moves it to column two.)

Comment: Now I'm working on Ubuntu 18.04 and `++kill=term` gave me an error: Invalid attribute: kill. Do you know how to slove this?

Comment: @Yves You might have an older version of Vim... Or are you on NeoVim? Can you upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04? Otherwise, search for a Ubuntu PPA with a newer Vim package...

Comment: Yea you are right, the verison of my vim in Ubuntu 18.04 is 8.0, instead of 8.2. I'll upgrade it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following keys to move a window:

- <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (to right),
- <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (to left),
- <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (to top),
- <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (to bottom).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
:set splitright
```

combined with a command abbreviation like:

```
:ca term vert term
```

Splits will always open on the right; `term` will always shortcut to `vert term` on the command line (this includes when using `/` and `?`).

Comment: I can’t really recommend an abbreviation here like this; it should at least only affect the Ex prompt and not searches. I also highly recommend spelling out commands (and using `:cnoreabbrev`).